# JSP Ajax populate drop down list based on the selected value

Tags: ajax, jsp

I have a drop down list will retrieve all product category from database and populate, another drop down list will show the product name based on the category selected by user.I am able to populate category but I was stuck at the product part

```
 <p>
                            <label for="pcategory">Product Category</label>
                            <select name="pcategory" size="0" onchange="get_product(this.selectedIndex);">
                                <%
                                            Category cat = new Category();
                                            java.util.ArrayList<Category> catList = cat.retrieveCategory();
                                            for (int i = 0; i < catList.size(); i++) {
                                %>
                                <option value="<%=(i + 1)%>"><%=catList.get(i).getCatname()%></option>
                                <%
                                            }
                                %>
                            </select>
                        </p>
                            <jsp:include page="data.jsp"/>

 function get_product(category){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "data.jsp",
                data: "category=" + category,
                success: function(msg){

                }
            });
        }
```

This is for data.jsp

```
<p>
<label for="pname">Product Name:</label>
<select name="state" id="state">
    <%
                if (request.getParameter("category") != null) {
    %>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <%      } else {
    %>
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="2">3</option>
    <%    }%>
</select>
```

my data.jsp will populate the product name. By default will populate the first category from database if user never change the category drop down list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do the following simple example using a servlet to get product names based on a product category.  You'll need to modify it a little bit to fit into your particular scenario.  Let me know if this is helpful and puts you down the right path...

The HTML page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <SCRIPT SRC="jquery.js" TYPE="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <label for="pcategory">Product Category</label>
            <select name="pcategory" id="pcategory" size="0">
                <option value="1">Category 1</option>
                <option value="2">Category 2</option>
                <option value="3">Category 3</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="pname">Product Name:</label>
            <select name="state" id="state">
                <option value="1">Product Name 1 For Category 1</option>
                <option value="2">Product Name 2 For Category 1</option>
                <option value="3">Product Name 3 For Category 1</option>
            </select>
        </p>        
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $category = $('#pcategory');

        $category.change (
            function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "GetProductName",
                    data: {category: $category.attr("selectedIndex") },
                    success: function(data){
                        $("#state").html(data)
                    }
                });
            }
        );
    </script>
</html>
```

The servlet which will give you the product names...

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class GetProductName extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            int category = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("category"));

            switch (category) {
                case 1:  
                    out.print(
                        "<option value='1'>Product Name 1 For Category 2</option>" +
                        "<option value='2'>Product Name 2 For Category 2</option>" +
                        "<option value='3'>Product Name 3 For Category 2</option>"
                    );
                    break;
                case 2:  
                    out.print(
                        "<option value='1'>Product Name 1 For Category 3</option>" +
                        "<option value='2'>Product Name 2 For Category 3</option>" +
                        "<option value='3'>Product Name 3 For Category 3</option>"
                    );
                    break;
                default:
                    out.print(
                        "<option value='1'>Product Name 1 For Category 1</option>" +
                        "<option value='2'>Product Name 2 For Category 1</option>" +
                        "<option value='3'>Product Name 3 For Category 1</option>"
                    );
                    break;
            }
        }  catch (Exception ex) {
            out.print("Error getting product name..." + ex.toString());
        }
        finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I cant get it work as the I think it never call the ajax.

Comment: Do you have the servlet setup correctly (GetProductName in my example above)?  You might want to try "System.out.println" in the servlet to see if it's getting to the servlet and you might try "alert" in your javascript to test as well.

Comment: Ya tried buy didnt call  and alert, but instead of         $category.change  I used onChange="GetProductName(this.selectedvalue) can work thanks for your help.