# populate selectbox from mysqldatabase

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp

I need to populate select box from database.Connectivity with database is success and i can retrieve and insert to the database.I tried the following code for populating the select box.But It shows an error "Iterator cannot be resolved to a type".
Java code for retreiving from database is,

```
 package servicescheduler.pack;
 import java.text.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.sql.*; 

 public class listObject 
{
   static Connection currentCon = null;
String sql="select * from center_point_map where service_center='Radiology';";
public List getlist()
{
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    try
    {
        currentCon = ConnectionManager.getconnection(); 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { 
        System.out.println(" An Exception has occurred! " + ex);      
    }
    if(currentCon!=null)
    {
        System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement prest = currentCon.prepareStatement(sql);
             ResultSet rs = prest.executeQuery();
             while(rs.next()) {
                    list.add(rs.getString(1));
                }
             System.out.println(list.get(0));
             prest.close();
             rs.close();
             return list;

        }
        catch (SQLException s)
        {
              System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!"+s);

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
              e.printStackTrace();

        }
      }

      return list;
  }

}
```

jsp code is

```
      <%@page import="servicescheduler.pack.listObject"%>
      <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/html4 /loose.dtd">
  <html>
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<select>
<%
Iterator it = new listObject().getlist();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    out.write("<option value=\""+ it.getFieldA()+ "\">"+ it.getFieldB() +"\">");
}
%>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you can get a lift from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643096/jsp-ajax-populate-drop-down-list-based-on-the-selected-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error because of import statements.You need to import Iterator in jsp also.The default package is `java.lang`.But here we are using Iterator which is available in `java.util.*`.
So you need to import java.util package first.

```
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
```

and use this

```
Iterator it = new listObject().getlist().iterator();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are assigning List to the iterator you are creating in your jsp code. Have a look at it.

Hence the code should be :

```
Iterator it = new listObject().getlist().iterator();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two wrong points in your jsp code

- The first: can not convert from List to Iterator. It should be `Iterator it = new listObject().getlist().iterator();`
- The second: In the while loop you must use `it.next()` to change pointer position to next