# Netbeans populating a dropdown list based on another dropdownlist html netbeans

Tags: java, javascript, sql, jsp, netbeans

i have an interface where i have two dropdownlists in html,one is mark(marque) of a phone and another is model.so the one of mark works fine(callin data from database(sql)) but i want that each time i choose the dropdown list of model it should not show the whole list of data concerning models from the database but just specific for the marque chosen without refreshin the page.like if i choose the mark Nokia it will automatically show just models of nokia not samsung or any other phone mark! i dont know if mayb its  sql on model as in the table model i have (model_tel,marque_tel(which is a foreign key from marque_tel)) so i tryed to use the where command for sql  but its not workin because i want to say where marquel_tel='//the marque chosen in the marque dropdownist//' but i dnt know how to do that 
in java (html)

the problem is i dont no much about javacsript or ajax.......so if any of u can help it would really mean alot

heres how the example of the code looks like so far(i just wwent straight to the main point here):

```
<label>Marque:

 <span class="small">selectionner la marque</span></label>

<%ResultSet rst = in.executeQuery("select distinct(Marque_Tel) from Marque_Tel");%> 

<table id="d"><tr><td id="k">
       <select name="marque" id="marque"  onchange="displayDate(this)">
       <% while (rst.next()) {%>
       <option></option>
      <option><%=rst.getString(1)%></option> //showin marksfrom data of sql//
      <% }%>`

   </td></tr></table><br><br><br>
            <label>Modele:
           span class="small">selectionner le modele</span></label>
            //callin phone models from sql database down here//

            <%ResultSet rs = in.executeQuery("select * from Modéle_Tel where           
      marque_tel='"+rst.getString(1).toString()//but this in not workin//"' ");%>

     <select name="modele" id="modele" >
       <% while (rs.next()) {%>
       <option></option>
      <option><%=rs.getString(1)%></option>//callin phones models
           </select>

                <button type="submit">VALIDER</button>  </html>
```

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643096/jsp-ajax-populate-drop-down-list-based-on-the-selected-value

Comment: @slacker thanks for the link but its not quite workin still...ill try again let me see!! :)

Comment: I think you better start with the basics of using ajax in jsp. Otherwise it will be difficult for you to implement the above. All the best.

Comment: yeah..ill pretty soon!!!! its just that im doin attachments and they gave me a job to do but we havent done that yet at school! thnks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **Ajax** for this problem. You cant get populated dropdown list based on another dropdown list without refreshing the page. So, the only option is to use **Ajax**.

Comment: thnx @gaurav.... thats the problem i havent yet done ajax or javascript..but its o good!!