# Dependent dropdown list not working

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

In one of my JSP Page I want to create dynamic drop down list where second drop down list depends on first dropdown list selection. I am able to populate data in first dropdown list from database . But for the second dropdown list its not working.  I want data for the second dropdown list from database based on selected data of first drop down box .  I have tried below code.

```
   <% 
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl" ,"hr", "password");

        ArrayList<String> uniList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String query = "select distinct cname from course ";
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
           uniList.add(rs.getString("cname"));
        }
          pageContext.setAttribute("authors", uniList);
    %>

      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

     function dropdownlist2(listindex)
     {
     String query2 = "select module from course where cname=?";
     PreparedStatement st2 = con.prepareStatement(query2);
     st2.setString(1,listindex);
     ResultSet rs2=st2.executQuery();
     ArrayList<String> uniList1 = new ArrayList<String>();

     while (rs.next()) {

           uniList1.add(rs2.getString("module"));
        }
     pageContext.setAttribute("authors1", uniList1);
     }
     </script>


        <form name="addteacher" onsubmit="" >
        <center>
       <table width="50%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5"> 
<tr>
<th align=left>Faculty Name :</th><td align=left><input type=text name=tname size="30" ></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <th align=left>Enter Course :</th><td align=left><select name="Coursebox" onchange="javascript: dropdownlist2(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
                                <option values="">-select-</option>
                                <c:forEach var="cn" items="${authors}">
                                    <option value="${cn}">${cn}</option>
                                </c:forEach></select></td></tr>
        <tr><th align=left>Enter Module:</th>
        <td align=left><select name="dname" size="1">
        <c:forEach var="cn1" items="${authors1}">
         <option value="${cn1}">${cn1}</option>
         </c:forEach>
        </select></td> </tr> </table>  </center>    </form>
```

Thanks

Comment: you are writing `java` code inside `script` tag.

Comment: Hi Satya, could you please help me with little more explanation. As I understand for second drop down list, i need to call onchange method with the selected value from first drop down list. Because of that I used in this way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643096/jsp-ajax-populate-drop-down-list-based-on-the-selected-value

Comment: see my answer it ll works. @Rohit khandelwal

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an ajax request to your servlet in order to get the values for 
the second drop down list.

The Javascript part is:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function dropdownlist2(listindex)
 {

$.ajax({ type: "GET",   
     url: "/MyServlet?index="+listindex,   
     success : function(text)
     {
        alert(text);

     }
    });
  }
 </script>
```

The servlet part is (use org.json.simple):

```
   /**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public MyServlet() 
{
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 request.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");
    response.setContentType("application/json"); 
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 

/*your code*/
    int listindex = request.getParameter("index");
String query2 = "select module from course where cname=?";
 PreparedStatement st2 = con.prepareStatement(query2);
 st2.setString(1,listindex);
 ResultSet rs2=st2.executQuery();

 JSONArray uniList1 = new JSONArray();
 while (rs.next()) {

       uniList1.add(rs2.getString("module"));
    }


    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("authors1", uniList1 );

    out.print(obj);
}
```

Comment: Hi @user5001333 i tried it but its not showing any data in second dropdown list. Thanks

Comment: I am facing issue now with success method as its not getting executed. As you suggested I have created a jsp page and in that calling servlet through ajax call .In the Servlet I am using Json object for returning values for dropdown . Values are correctly coming in Json object But The request is getting completed with some error (as success method is not getting called instead error method is called ) . I have posted a question on it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639178/success-callback-function-is-not-called-when-ajax-call-to-servlet . Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rohitkhandelwal sorry i was in vacation. Did you find a solution ? It is because some requests throw exceptions. On the servlet side you need to wrap the portion of code in a try-catch block and print the error in the catch clause with `out.print(exception.getMessage())`

Answer (score 1):

You need two jsps. One for filling first drop down and getting dependent value and another for filling second drop down. Here I'm giving some example code. So change according to your needs means change `connection` settings, adding `jstl` library, etc. You need a `ajax` call to fill second drop down.

Mistakes in your code:

1. You are writing java code in script tag.
2. Populating second drop down

In first jsp (index.jsp)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
var keys=document.dummy.sele.value
var urls="fetch.jsp?ok="+keys//to fill second drop down
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {    
removeall();     
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
    {//is success, then fill second drop down
            z=0;
            var roott=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
            var ress=roott.getElementsByTagName("empname")[z].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

            while(ress!=null)
            {
                    addoptions(ress)
                    z++
             var ress=roott.getElementsByTagName("empname")[z].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            }
    }

    function removeall()
    {

        var ct=document.dummy.sele2.length;
        for(i=ct; i>=0; i--)    {    
            document.dummy.sele2.options[i]=null;
             }
    }

    function addoptions(reslt)
    {

        var ct1=document.createElement("OPTION");
        ct1.text=reslt;
        ct1.value=reslt;
        document.dummy.sele2.options.add(ct1);

    }
}    

xmlhttp.open("GET",urls,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="dummy">
<font face="verdana" size="2">
<!-- your first drop down with java and jstl code should be here -->
Employee Number:    <select name="sele" onchange="loadXMLDoc()">
            <option>select</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
            <option value="101">101</option>
    </select>
 <!-- second drop down will come based on first drop down value as you selected-->
Employee Name:    <select name="sele2">
            <option>--choose--</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

In second jsp (fetch.jsp)

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%
            response.setContentType("text/xml");
            String sn=request.getParameter("ok");
            int i=Integer.parseInt(sn);

                    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                    Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","admin");
                    Statement st=con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select empname from emp where empno="+i);

                    out.println("<emp>");
                    while(rs.next())
                    {                            
                        out.println("<empname>"+rs.getString(1)+"</empname>");

                    }
                    out.println("</emp>");

rs.close();
st.close();
con.close();

%>
```