# success callback function is not called when ajax call to servlet

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsp, servlets

I am trying to make dependent drop down list. For that I have created a jsp page and in that calling servlet through ajax call .In the servlet I am using Json object for returning values for dropdown . Values are correctly coming in Json object But The request is getting completed with some error (as success method is not getting called instead error method is called ) .

Here is my ajax code :

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",   
             url: "MyServlet?index="+listindex, 
             datatype: 'JSON', 
              error : function() {

            alert("Error");
              },
            success : function(data) {
       try{
        var citiArray=JSON.parse(data);

        if(citiArray != null){

        for(var s=0;s<citiArray.length;s++){

        var serial=citiArray[s];
        //populating drop down list
           $("#dname").append($("<option></option>").val(serial.authors1).html(serial.authors1));
        }
        }
        }
             catch(err){
             alert(err);
                 }
            }
     });
```

`My Servlet code :MyServlet.java`

```
 public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
   /**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public MyServlet() 
{
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

   try { 

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl" ,"hr", "password");

     request.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");
    response.setContentType("application/json"); 
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 

    String listindex = request.getParameter("index");
    out.print(listindex);
  String query2 = "select module from course where cname=?";
 PreparedStatement st2 = con.prepareStatement(query2);
 st2.setString(1,listindex);
 ResultSet rs2=st2.executeQuery();

  JSONArray uniList1 = new JSONArray();
  while (rs2.next()) 
   {
       uniList1.add(rs2.getString("module"));
       //System.out.println(rs2.getString("module"));
    }


    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("key", uniList1 );
    System.out.println(obj);
    out.print(obj);
  }
   catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

`web.xml:`

```
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>  
  <servlet-class>com.dac.MyServlet</servlet-class>  
  </servlet>  

  <servlet-mapping>  
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>  
  <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Thanks
Rohit

Comment: Do some basic debugging. Make your error function do something useful: examine the three arguments it is passed. Also look in your browser's Developer Tools. The Net tab will show you what request you are making and what response you are getting, the Console tab will show you JS errors.

Comment: Also, intent your code properly. It's too messy to read easily.

Comment: I am getting the correct response .

Comment: If the error function is being called then it is unlikely that the response is actually correct. See also, all the other debugging techniques I mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Send a response even if an exception is thrown

```
 catch (Exception e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    //send the response
    out.print(e.getMessage());
}
```

You can have a detailed description of the error with:

```
 error: function (theRequest, theStatus, theError) 
 {
    alert(theRequest.responseText);
}
```

instead of

```
  error : function() {

        alert("Error");
          }
```