# How to make dependable drop down where their values are fetching from database

Tags: java, database, jsp

These are the two drop down lista. The valuea for this drop down list are fetching from data base. Now I want to make state drop down list dependable on country drop down list.

```
`<td><select name = "Country" id ="Country">
              <option value =""select Disabled>select County</option>
                <%`
`try{
  string query ="select country from countries";
  Connection con = sqlConnection.getConnection();
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  while(rs.next())
  {`
   `%>
   <option value ="<%=rs.getString(1)%"> <%=rs.getString(1) %></option>
   <%` 
  `} 
`}
`catch (Exception ex)
{
  System.out.println(ex);`
`}`

`</select></td>
<tr>`

    `<td><select name = "state" id ="state">
              <option value =""select Disabled>select County</option>
                <%
`<td><select name = "state" id ="state">
              <option value =""select Disabled>select County</option>
                <%`
`try{
  string query ="select state from states";
  Connection con = sqlConnection.getConnection();
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  while(rs.next())`
  `{`
  `%>
   <option value ="<%=rs.getString(1)%"> <%=rs.getString(1) %></option>
   <% ` 
  `} 
`}

catch (Exception ex)
{`
  `System.out.println(ex);
}`

</select></td>
<tr>
```

The column name and list of value in the data base are as follows:

```
`country         states`

`India          Karnataka`
               `Tamil Nadu`
               `Andhra`

`Australia      queens land`
               `Victoria`

`USA            California`
               `Washington`
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: may be using `ajax` and `jquery` would help .Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8648844/10606400).

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad code, why do you want to have database calls from JSP and that too using scriptlets? A better approach would be to create a Service class which calls your DAO class, there you can have your Db calls and return the JSON to the jsp with all the details of country and state mappings as key-values. Now, once you have the JSON use javascript to show the states in the dropdown based on the selected country.